# Linux How to run python script on startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, python

Linux Ubuntu 14.04
Have a script in ~/app/serve.py

Need to run it in this folder. In shell I may do

```
> cd ~/app && python serve.py
```

and it runs a server

Need to run it on servers boot in background. Tried to add this command `cd ~/app && python serve.py ~` in etc/rc.local (and etc/init.d/rc.local) but it doesn't start.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding `cd ~/app && python serve.py` in /etc/rc.local, try putting in the entire path.  You are expecting the init process to know that ~ is your home directory somehow, but init starts as root.  Because init starts as root, it's looking in `/` for the app directory not your home directory.  Get rid of the ~ by using the path to your home directory.

Try adding  `/home/whitecolor/app/serve.py` to `/etc/rc.local`.  (`pwd` to find your pathway directory.) Get rid of the `python` in front of your serve.py script by adding `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of your script.  (type a `which python` to find the path in case it isn't installed in the normal place)

Edit: You did say "run in the background", and I missed that.  To run a command in the background, add a `&` after the command.  So, to background that command above:  `/home/whitecolor/app/serve.py &`  Init doesn't usually need the background symbol to start a job and run it in the background.

DrDR's excellent suggestion would not need the same `&` treatment after the command in the cron startup as those are run in the background by default.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I needed to replace ~ with needed user home. Thank you very much)

Answer (score 4):

I've never had the need to try this, but apparently scripts can be run at system startup via cron by adding a line similar to the one beginning with @reboot below.

```
#m  h  dom  mon  dow  command
1   *  *    *    *    someHourlyCommand
@reboot               python /home/<username>/app/serve.py
```

Note, I've changed the command slightly to eliminate cd'ing into the directory.  Your situation may be different, so do what works for you.

Comment: I believe it is `@reboot`, not `@startup`, see here, http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab under Extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, MariusMatutiae.  I've edited my answer accordingly.